# Issue updating second orbiting body in a processing.js example

Tags: javascript, physics, processing, processing.js

I was given a processing.js example of how to orbit an object around another object by a user on gamedev.stackexchange [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50635/revolve-flxsprites-around-a-central-flxsprite-in-flash-game-made-with-flixel).

Essentially, in the example, an origin or center is established along with the cooridinates of the orbiting point:

```
// Logic vars
PVector origin;
float orbitRadius = 75.0;
PVector orbitVelocity;
PVector orbitPoint;
float t = 0.0;
float fps = 60.0;
float constDT = 1 / fps;
```

Then, they are initialized in the setup:

```
void setup() {
    size(400, 400);
    frameRate(fps);

    /*central point */
    origin = new PVector(width / 2.0, height / 2.0);

    /*first point and velocity of orb around center*/
    orbitVelocity = new PVector(0.0, /*-orbitRadius*/orbitRadius);
    orbitPoint = new PVector(origin.x + orbitRadius, origin.y);
}
```

And then the cooridinates of the orbiting point are updated each time step:

```
void update(float dt) {

    /*update orbit of first orb using velocity*/
    PVector accelerationTowardsOrigin = PVector.sub(origin, orbitPoint);
    orbitVelocity.add(PVector.mult(accelerationTowardsOrigin, /*dt*/constDT));
    orbitPoint.add(PVector.mult(orbitVelocity, /*dt*/constDT));

}
```

(I have omitted the drawing code as it is not relevant.) I have been attempting to update the code to add additional orbiting ellipses, which can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XhPzL/28/).  I have been able to successfully add a second point along orbit around the central point by adding these additional variables

```
/*Logic vars for second point on circle*/
PVector orbitPoint2;
PVector orbitVelocity2;
float circAngle;
float xcoord_along_circle;
float ycoord_along_circle;
```

and adding this to setup:

```
    //Added in setup
    /*second orbiting point for second orb*/
    /*Calculate second point along circle*/
    circAngle = 90.0;
    xcoord_along_circle = orbitRadius * cos(circAngle) + origin.x;
    ycoord_along_circle = orbitRadius * sin(circAngle) + origin.y;

    /*second point and velocity of orb around center*/
    orbitVelocity2 = new PVector(xcoord_along_circle,orbitRadius);
    orbitPoint2 = new PVector(xcoord_along_circle, ycoord_along_circle);
```

However, when I update the cooridinates of the second ellipse each point it results in a stretched out, elongated orbit:

```
 /*update orbit of second orb using velocity*/
    PVector accelerationTowardsOrigin2 = PVector.sub(origin,orbitPoint2);
    orbitVelocity2.add(PVector.mult(accelerationTowardsOrigin2,/*dt*/constDT));
    orbitPoint2.add(PVector.mult(orbitVelocity2, /*dt*/constDT));
```

I believe I am doing everything correctly, and replicating the necessary steps. How can I correct this so that the orbit is not distorted?

Comment: I changed my answer from a comment to a normal answer, but I'd like to point out your fiddle uses Pjs 1.0, which is ancient at this point. The latest version is 1.4.1, and jsfiddle has it in its list of Pjs libraries to pick from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point you're duplicating code all over the place rather than modularising your code by capturing the orbiting bodies in a class that you can simply build a million times. I'd suggest first rewriting your code to something like

```
class OrbitalBody {
    float ox, oy, x, y, m, a;
    OrbitalBody(float originX, float originY, float startX, float startY, float mass, float speed) {
      ox = originX;
      oy = originY;
      x = startX;
      y = startY;
      m = mass;
      a = speed / 200;
    }
    void update() {
      float nx = (x-ox) * cos(a) - (y-oy) * sin(a),
            ny = (x-ox) * sin(a) + (y-oy) * cos(a);
      x = nx+ox;
      y = ny+oy;
    }
    void draw() {
      fill(255);
      ellipse(x,y,m,m);
    }
}

ArrayList<OrbitalBody> bodies = new ArrayList<OrbitalBody>();
int mx, my;

void setup() {
    size(420, 420);
    mx = width/2;
    my = height/2;
    bodies.add(new OrbitalBody(mx, my, mx-50, my, 10, 10));
    bodies.add(new OrbitalBody(mx, my, mx-100, my, 20, 3));
    bodies.add(new OrbitalBody(mx, my, mx-120, my, 5, 13));
    bodies.add(new OrbitalBody(mx, my, mx-170, my, 15, 6));
    bodies.add(new OrbitalBody(mx, my, mx-190, my, 10, 9));
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
    fill(100,100,0);
    ellipse(mx,my,50,50);
    for(OrbitalBody b: bodies) {
        b.update();
        b.draw();
    }
}
```

demonstrator: http://jsfiddle.net/XhPzL/34

Comment: Ok, yeah this is a really cool example and I was able to tweak it to achieve a result I wanted to test using the class you provided. I had not modularised the code because I was just attempting to make a simple addition to test a functionality, but your organization made it a lot more efficient and usable anyways, so thank you.

Comment: you're quite welcome. If this is the answer you were looking for, make sure to hit the "this is the correct answer" check mark next to the post so this question doesn't stay listed as "unanswered" =)